# Importdata out of memory error

Tags: matlab

I am running into issues with importdata throwing an "Out of Memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program." error.  I have previously been able to use the command on the same file without problems, but now am getting it intermittently after using it in a function.

CSV to insert:  516 rows, 14403 columns (29 mb file size) data is 2 columns text 2-5 characters long and 14401 columns of integers.

Script to import:

```
testdata = importdata('filename.csv')
```

Custom Function (reads file, tells me location of repeats in data, and spits out an output with summary:

```
function [] = evaldata(filename)

testdata=importdata(filename);
a = cellstr(testdata.textdata);
b = strncmp('I',a,2);
c = find(b(:,2));
d = c(2) - c(1);
e = length(a);
f = a(1:1:d,2);
str = strjoin(f,', ');
fprintf('\nFile %s has %d rows, with %d unique channels(%s).\n',file,e,d,str)
```

When I run memory I see 8115 mb RAM available, 1160 mb used by MATLAB, and maximum possible array 4194 mb.  I can't imagine this importdata function is generating enough data to run out of memory.

clearall, inmem/pack etc all haven't helped.

Ultimately i will need to scale up to run a number of tasks on up to 50-100 files like the one coming in above.

If anyone has insight on why this error is being generated or how to adjust my code to optimize data management, I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit:
After reboot, I can run my importdata command successfully.  Memory tests show the same amount of memory free.  It seems that I get this error after running a function that has an importdata command in it.

`testdata=importdata('1373.csv')`;  works perfectly, then:

```
evaldata('1373.csv')
```

Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.

Error in importdata (line 3)
ekgdata=importdata(filename);

Comment: I addended my post with the full function that I made.  evaldata is a custom function but doesn't do much more than a few comparisons.  independently the import section of my function works fine and the remaining calculations and output run fine.

Comment: Can you change to another file I/O function such as `dlmread` or `fread`? `importdata` running into an infinite loop when placed in a function but not when called separately is weird indeed.

Comment: Is it data dependent? Try smaller csv file, with different data. Upload a csv file that reproduce the problem...

Comment: I'll try some other I/O functions, I was able to use csvread to read only the numeric elements of the file, but the text data in the first two columns is critical for the other analyses - the net memory use on the csv read was only 40 mb of RAM.  When I am able to import using importdata, the memory use is only about 100 mb, far less than the available memory.  I may try to reinstall my matlab, as I did recently upgrade windows 10 to the latest update and perhaps the memory allocation/setup is somehow altered.